# Angular - Patch selected value in Select drop-down only when value matches

Tags: html, angularjs, typescript, angular7, angular-reactive-forms

I want to patch value for `<select>` dropdown in Reactive form with the matching value.

However, if no matching value is present, the `<select>` should be empty or show a default selection as 'Select value', which should not make the form valid.

The happy scenario of value getting matched works, but when value doesn't match, the  shows the first option in the list as selected, and the form becomes valid.

**index.html**

```
<div class="form-group" *ngIf="{port: port$ | async} as _port$">
    <label for="country">Country</label>
    <select [attr.disabled]="!_port$.port?.length > 0 ? 'disabled' : null" id="country" formControlName="countryCode"
            class="form-control form-control-lg">
      <option disabled value="null">Enter Country type</option>
      <option *ngFor="let type of _port$.port"
              [value]="type.code" [selected]="type.code == countryCode ">{{type.label}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

**index.ts**

```
this.form.controls[fieldName].patchValue(value);
```

**example response json**

```
port$ = [{
        "code": "1",
        "label": "YEMEN"
      },
      {
        " code ": "2",
        " label ": "ZAMBIA"
      },
      {
        " code ": "3",
        " label ": "ZIMBABWE"
      }]
```